# duplicate HTTP POST from python script with Lua

Tags: php, python, http, post, lua

I have a python script which succesfully posts a file to my localhost webserver running apache in <100ms. Now, I want to do exactly the same with Lua. I have come up with a script that posts that same image to my webserver but it takes a whopping ~24s to complete. The php running on the server receives and stores the file properly **but** for the Python script, the file comes in the `$_FILES` array whereas for the Lua script, I have to copy content from the `php://input` stream - also, looking at both POST requests with wireshark, I can see a `7667 POST` from the Python script but not from the Lua, instead only a few TCP SYN & ACK frames. Any idea why my Lua script is missing the actual POST (incl. url) but it still seems to work (but really slow):
Some code is below:

**Python**

```
#!/usr/bin/python


import urllib2
import time
from binascii import hexlify, unhexlify
import MultipartPostHandler


fname="test.gif"
host = "localhost"
#host = "semioslive.com"
URI="/test.php"
#URI="/api/gateway.php"
nodemac ="AABBCC"
timestamp = int(time.time())
func="post_img"

url = "http://{0}{1}?f={2}&nodemac={3}&time={4}".format(host, URI,func,nodemac,timestamp)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(MultipartPostHandler.MultipartPostHandler)

data = {"data":open(fname,"rb")}

#r.get_method = lambda: 'PUT'
now = time.time()
response = opener.open(url, data, 120)
retval = response.read()

if "SUCCESS" in retval:
        print "SUCCESS"
else:
        print "RESPONSE sent at "+retval
        print "             Now "+str(time.time())


print "Request took "+str(time.time()-now)+"s to return"
```

**Lua**

```
#! /usr/bin/lua

http = require("socket.http")
ltn12 = require("ltn12")

local request_body = ltn12.source.file(io.open("test.gif"))

local response_body = {}


http.request{
    url = "`http://localohst/test.php`",  
    method = "POST",
    headers = {
        ["Content-Type"] =  "multipart/form-data",
        ["Content-Length"] = 7333
    },
    -- source = ltn12.source.file(io.open("test.gif")),
    source = request_body,
    sink = ltn12.sink.table(response_body)
}
print(response_body[1]) --response to request
```

**PHP**

```
<?
if (isset($_FILES['data']))
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['data']['tmp_name'],"post(python).gif");
else
    copy("php://input","post(lua).gif");

echo "SUCCESS!";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your Lua script is sending the same HTTP headers. The important part for PHP is that the form with attached file upload is sent as "multipart/form-data", and the file must be properly embedded in the POST body of the HTTP request as a multipart mime message.

I cannot see if your Lua script actually does this, but I think no. Otherwise PHP would be happy.